# Transpose notation

Tags: notation, transpose

After using the transpose for a while, I wondered if there in any vague connection to other superscript stuff like exponents or something. I doubt it, but I couldn't find anything and it seems weird to have it as a superscript. Is there anything deeper going on here?

Question: Is there a reason for this notation? It's bothered me from since I learned it.

Comment: Where else could we put the $T$? $A_T$ looks in the context of matrices like the $T$th component of a vector. I suppose we could use ${}^TA$ or ${}_TA$, or dispense with $T$ altogether with notation such as $\bar{A}$. Good luck keeping track of the difference between transposes and Hermitian adjoints of complex matrices then, though.

Comment: In fact some sources do use ${}^TA$. Other sources use a prime to indicate the transpose, with the obvious potential for confusion.

Comment: @J.G. What about T$(A)$

Answer (score 2):

It's just the conventional notation and is used for the [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) too: $\mathbf A^\mathsf {H}$.

As the Wikipedia entry on [the transpose of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) points out, you can use ${\mathbf  {A}}^{\top}$ (`\top`) instead of $\mathbf  {A}^{T}$ to make it stand out a bit better if that helps:

> To avoid confusing the reader between the transpose operation and a matrix raised to the $\mathbf A^{th}$ power, the $\mathbf  {A}^{\top}$ symbol denotes the transpose operation.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a real orthogonal matrix, then
$$A^{-1} = A^T$$

This is the only little thing I can think of.